# intersection of 2 lists retaining duplicates (without loop)

Tags: python, intersection

I have list1

```
list1 = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I have another list2

```
list2 = ["a", "d"]
```

I want the output as follows

```
out = ["a", "a", "d"]
```

I am doing following

```
> l1 = set(list1)
>>> l2 = set(list2)
>>> l1.intersection(l2)
```

But I am loosing duplicates of list1 here. ***The lists are in actual pretty big. Can't run loop. I need to use some fast efficient way only.***

Comment: @idjaw please check my last line. I don't want loop.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a loop of some sort. Even `set.intersection` will use a loop internally. The list comprehension in the dupe answer seems just right to me.